# download data from database online from google POI

Tags: database, download

I want to create an iPhone app that use the POI of google (for example a category, like baker shops or fish shops) and displays the POI on the map. I want to download all the data (name, address, telephone,..) abd put them into a database used by my app. Is it possible? How? There're tutorial or software to do this? I'm a beginner on database management. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to find them manually. Try to search a list of POI and then use Google Earth to find the coordinates of each of them..